# Not able to start Redis Sentinel Container in Docker

Tags: caching, redis, docker-compose, redis-cluster, redis-sentinel

I am trying to setup Redis sentinel on docker, but sentinel container is not starting. I have one Master and one Slave with one Sentinel.

I am using ec2 ubuntu instance (t2 micro), where i have installed docker.

This is docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  redis-master:
    container_name: "redis-master"
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    command: "redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"
    volumes:
      - "./data/master:/data/"
      - "./master.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"
    sysctls:
       - net.core.somaxconn=512
  redis-slave:
    container_name: "redis-slave"
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6380:6379"
    command: "redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/slave.conf"
    volumes:
      - "./data/slave:/data/"
      - "./slave.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/slave.conf"
    sysctls:
       - net.core.somaxconn=512
  redis-sentinel:
    container_name: "redis-sentinel"
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "26379:26379"
    command: "redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/sentinel.conf --sentinel"
    volumes:
      - "./sentinel.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/sentinel.conf"
    sysctls:
       - net.core.somaxconn=512
    depends_on:
      - redis-master
      - redis-slave
```

After starting i am getting the below error and sentinel container is getting killed

**Sentinel config file /usr/local/etc/redis/sentinel.conf is not writable: Permission denied. Exiting...**

Comment: What are the file permissions of the `sentinel.conf` file being added? Try doing a `chmod 777` on the file before adding.

Answer (score 0):

redis uses the redis user when it's up , so you can make

```
chown redis:redis /etc/redis/sentinel.conf
```

in your redis-sentinel dockerfile
or if you want to stick with the compose-file only, you can try

```
command: bash -c "
    chown redis:redis /etc/redis/sentinel.conf
    && redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/sentinel.conf --sentinel
  "
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occur because Sentinel needs write permission to the folder where the configuration file lives. Sentinel needs this permission to create temporary files and to be able to update the configuration file.